# News application for django

Tags: django, rss, feed

Is there a good news application for django framework? I've searched it and found several variants. I'm interested if you used one of them and can recommend me which one to use. I need some features to easily read(modify user side), edit with WYSIWYG(at admin area), and export news to an rss and atom feeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as you already may know there are *tons* of django blog apps, but if you want a recommendation that may fit your needs, [zinnia](https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-blog-zinnia) should be worth a try...

Comment: Wow! Thanks for that. I haven't seen it before. Looks very promising